# METRO SOAP web services not working with Tomcat 9 and Java 11

Tags: soap, java-11, ws-security, java-metro-framework

We have migrated our project from Java 8 to Java 11 and after that ws-security is not working in our application. 
Added

JVM_PARAMS="$JVM_PARAMS --upgrade-module-path /Tomcat/upgradable"

in setenv.sh file.
But still the jars internal to java is taking at runtime instead of the Metro webservices-rt jar. 
So where should I keep the
`webservices-extra.jar,webservices-extra-api.jar, webservices-rt.jar and webservices-tools.jar` ? 
Earlier it was there inside /shared/lib directory.

Comment: The `--upgrade-module-path` option is to specify the location of modules that upgrade/replace modules in the run-time image. The only upgradable modules in JDK 11 are `java.compiler ` and the modules for the experimental AOT and Graal compilers. I don't know anything about the Tomcat configuration but it sounds like you are looking for the WS-* libraries to be on the class path.

Comment: @Alan Bateman, we used to keep the webservices-api.jar inside endorsed folder of Tomcat and set that folder as the endorsed folder of jvm to pre load the classes before jvm classes. Also we were keeping impl and webservices-rt.jars at shared/lib folder of Tomcat. From Java 11 onwards , if we wants to use any third party implementation over jdk implementation, we have to use upgradable modules. But the same is not working with WS-security.

Comment: JAX-WS is not in Java SE 11 and newer so there is nothing to upgrade.

Comment: @Alan Bateman ,We are facing issue with JCAMapper class. This is available inside Metro webservices.rt.jar and java.xml.crypto ( inside JVM) . Till java 8 the METRO one was getting loaded and the algorithm Map was containing our entry. But from java 11 on wards , one from Crypto package is getting loaded and that doesn't have our Algorithm entry. So signature verification is failing now.

Comment: What is the fully quality name of JCAMapper? I don't see any class by that name in the JDK.

Comment: Sorry it is JCEMapper

Comment: But the same class is available inside the webservices-rt.jar of METRO which is used by ws-security . So i guess its a third party implementation for security. I could debug and see that the code is going into webservices-rt.jar - JCEMapper class in JDK-8 with the help of endorsed folder path in java( Tomcat endorsed and shared/lib directories)

Comment: Is METRO maintained by Eclipse now? This seems like something they should fix as it's insane to try to override a repackaged class in this way.